# Append timestamp on src or href attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, timestamp

For 2 days I've been looking an answer, but I can't find a good solution to my problem.

I'm developing a web application where I can only use standard front-end files (HTML, CSS, JavaScript (I use jQuery)). There's no back-end script merged with the HTML.

What I'm trying to achieve is to add an `<script>` tag to my HTML, but with a timestamp added as a variable, such as: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js?c=1421656264439"></script>`.

With PHP it would be simple to achieve, because you can just add the timestamp along with the HTML. But since I must work with front-end code only, what would be the best way to add a `script` or `link` tag with a timestamp, so the script doesn't get loaded from the cache?

Since the client uses Internet Explorer 10, I will need an answer that will work with that...

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: you can add the script element dynamically using javascript

Comment: like `var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'js/javascript.js?c=' + (new Date()).getTime());
document.head.appendChild(script);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While creating an element, setting the attributes and appending it to the document kind of worked, the beforeSend headers weren't set on the AJAX calls in the `javascript.js` for some reason. This was also the issue by using `$.getScripts('js/javascript.js');`

I suddenly realised that I could try a simple `document.write()` within a script tag. Turns out that it works like a charm.

My fix:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _c = new Date().getTime();
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascrtipt.js?c='+_c+'"><\/script>');
    </script>
</body>
```

(I can't believe I couldn't come up with this solution earlier)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with jQuery I recommend you to do it this way:

```
$.getScript( "js/javascript.js" );
```

From jQuery docs:

> By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested.

Comment: This works, kind of... It does load in with a timestamp! But it appears that all my AJAX calls within the javascript.js file are not behaving like they should. Non of them send a Reuqest header, which I set in the scripts, causing my AJAX functions to fail.

Comment: Can't do that unfortunately... :(

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [jQuery getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

I think it could solve your problem:

> By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Your suggestion does make sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically load the javascript/css. Also while loading add the random version.

e.g. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Anyway, I believe you already know what you are doing is not the best practice. In case of more specific requirement HTTP header can be set to no-cache for the JS/css files. This information can be set in the HTTP server being used without need of a programming language.

[How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that you could do this! Is there a proper way to test this in IE10?

Comment: Use Developer tools of IE. In the network tab see the HTTP code, 200 means that it has been loaded again.

Comment: That's obvious, but if I check in Chrome, I see a request header called "No-Caching" (so I can assume it's working), but it's not in the request header of IE10